# Kafka gzip values are getting corrupted inside topic

Tags: serialization, apache-camel, gzip, apache-kafka

I am trying to put gzip data into kafka and read it.  But , as I have seen, input byteArray and output byteArray is not same. I am pretty sure that the gzip format is right on producer side(I rechecked and printed values before submission) but when I get that value from kafka topic, it says

> "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format"

I printed data in both producerand consumer side. And ı have found that they are not same.

String values are working without any problem by the way. And my serializer config is:

```
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Am I missing something or is there a configuration to make it happen?

Thx a lot

Comment: Is it possible the consumer has decompressed it? See first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890894/kafka-message-codec-compress-and-decompress